# intuition behind asymmetry of Poisson distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, intuition, skewness

Today I've learned that the probability of the number of independent random events occurring in a fixed interval of time can be modeled with the Poisson distribution.
When thinking about it my intuition tells me that independent random events would be distributed symmetrically around the mean.
So why is it that the Poisson distribution is skewed in a manner that the lower number of events is more likely to occur than the higher number?

Comment: It's literally impossible to have a symmetrical distribution whose support is [0,inf]

Comment: And I guess even negatively skewed. So by a "proof by contradiction" type argument you could reason it intuitively has to be positively skewed.

Comment: Start with the idea that the possible counts are 0, 1, 2, 3, .... and that the mean count must be finite. (If there is a wired-in limit to the  count, the Poisson is not a suitable model any way.)

Comment: Intuition can start with thinking about data too. I was reading today of someone who liked guitars a lot and at one point had 25. I can tell you that I have zero guitars and I doubt that I am alone in that. And so on and so forth for counting what people have: children, cats, cars, and beyond. (A Poisson does not have to the best model in practice for any of these for thinking from data to help.)

Comment: @Dale It's possible for a distribution family to be supported on the non-negative numbers and for *every* member of the family to be *negatively* skewed.  Positivity (of support) does not imply positive skewness!  For better intuition, consider a situation where the Poisson rate is less than $1:$ that implies a high probability of a zero count. For sufficiently low rates that probability must exceed $1/2$ (intuitively, that will be the case for any rate less than $1/2,$ at least), which obviously gives a skewed distribution.

Comment: @whuber Ah you're right. That makes sense, I thought it might not be the case but couldn't immediately see why not, but thanks, your argument is very clean. I'll leave up my incorrect comment though maybe so your reply has context.